# Congruence Class

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having a hard time with number theory, I'm being asked to determine congruence classes of inverses. I'm hoping someone could give me a step by step walkthrough of the process to solve one of these:

Determine the congruence class of:
$$\overline{5}^{12} \ \ \  in\ \ \  \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\overline{3}^{61} \ \ \  in \ \ \  \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\overline{3}^{26} \ \ \  in\ \ \  \mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$$

edit: I think I kind of have an idea how to do it if there were no inverse bars, but I'm really weak in math so I could be wrong there too.

Here's my attempt at the first one:
$$\overline{5}^{12}
 in \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$$

$$5\equiv x\ (mod\ 7)$$
 . x must be -2 for the statement to be true.

$$(5)^{12}\equiv(-2)^{12}\equiv((-2)^{3})^{4}\equiv-8^{4}\equiv-1^{4}\equiv1\ (mod\ 7) $$

Is this correct?

Comment: This doesn't seem like determining congruence classes of inverses. It looks like an application of repeated squaring $\pmod p$. What do you mean when you say inverse bars? As far as I know, $\bar{3}$ denotes the congruence class of $3$ and has nothing to do with inverses.

Comment: You are probably right in that regard, I'm just further demonstrating my clueless-ness. Would you be willing to choose one or give me hints on how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to write $5^{12}$: the bars are strictly speaking correct, but I think that very few people use them in practice.

The simplest way to think of this is that in $\def\Z{{\Bbb Z}}\Z/7\Z$, the number $7$ counts the same as zero.  For example, $33=4\times7+5$ counts the same as $4\times0+5$, which is $5$.  We write
$$33\equiv5\pmod7$$
or
$$33=5\quad\hbox{in}\quad \Z/7\Z\ .$$
The easiest way to simplify powers (if you are just beginning - there are more advanced ways which you may learn later) is to start off with some trial and error.  Thus
$$\eqalign{
  5^2&\equiv25=3\times7+4\equiv4\pmod7\cr
  5^3=5^2\times5&\equiv4\times5=3\times7-1\equiv-1\pmod7\ .\cr}$$
And once you have a result of $-1$ (or $1$, even easier), you can find higher powers very quickly:
$$5^{12}=(5^3)^4\equiv(-1)^4=1\pmod7\ .$$
See if you can do the others for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I very much appreciate the thought of 7 counting the same as zero. This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, it wants you to determine the congruence class of $\bar{5}^{12}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$. We notice that $\bar{5}^{12} = \bar{5}^8 \times \bar{5}^4$. The we have $\bar{5}^2 = \overline{25} = \overline{25 \pmod 7} = \overline {4}$. We also have that $\bar{5}^4 = {\bar{5}^2}^2 = \bar{4}^2 = \overline{16 \pmod 7} = \bar{2}$ and $\bar{5}^8 = {\bar{5}^4}^2 = \bar{2}^2 = \bar 4$.

Putting this together, we obtain $\bar{5}^{12} = \bar{5}^8 \times \bar{5}^4 = \overline{2 \times 4 \pmod 7} = \bar{1}$.

As you can see, it takes a bit of work, but it really just comes down to arithmetics. See if you can replicate this method for the other two. Start by writing the exponent as a sum of powers of 2 to minimise calculations.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, I appreciate looking at it in a different way than my own. I'll try this with the other 2.